# async await and Task in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await

I'm testing the **async await and task** functionality but it seems i'm missing something

When I write like this **A being starting point**.

```
void A()
{
   Debug.WriteLine("pre B");
   B();
   Debug.WriteLine("post B");
}

async void B()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("pre C");
    await C();
    Debug.WriteLine("post C")
}

async Task C()
{
   await Task.Yield();
   Debug.WriteLine("pre D");
   await D();
   Debug.WriteLine("post D");
}

async Task D()
{
   Debug.WriteLine("inside D");
}
```

I get output in debug console as

```
pre B,
pre C,
pre D,
inside D,
post D,
post C,
post B
```

Is it running asynchronously?? I guess not, what thought it should run like

```
pre B,
pre C,
post B,
post C,
pre D,
inside D,
post D
```

So what's the problem here?

Comment: Just because it's running asynchronously doesn't mean the order will be how you expect. Try putting some sleeps in your functions to make sure they don't complete too fast.

Comment: Since you don't have any blocking operations in C() and D(), all is cpu bound, therefore yes, it runs synhconously.

Comment: @OguzOzgul can it not run on multiple cores?

Comment: The only one likely to move is the `post B` output. Read the B method's body to yourself (similarly for C) - write `pre C`, then wait until C has finished, then write `post C`. Logically, `post C` can't be written until C has finished. At which point, all of the messages relating to `D` must already have been written.

Comment: They run on the same thread, so, no.

Comment: I'm guessing that you've got a misunderstanding of `async`/`await` that would normally be cured by reading [Asynchronous Programming in C# 5.0 part two: Whence await?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) by Eric Lippert - e.g. " The whole point of async methods it that you stay on the current thread as much as possible"

Comment: i changed the code and added Thead.Sleep(2000) before and After Every Debug.WriteLine(), But the sequence remains the same. and as you link says  "if the task we are awaiting has not yet completed then sign up the rest of this method as the continuation of that task, and then return to your caller immediately; the task will invoke the continuation when it completes". Why its not happening here

Comment: any new info on this?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you read my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and follow up with my [`async` best practices article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In particular, one of the best practices is to only use `async void` for event handlers.

The whole point of `async` is to enable asynchronous code *while keeping that code written in a similar way to synchronous code*. So if an outer method `await`s the task returned from an inner method, then the outer method *will not continue executing* until the inner method completes.

So, for example, synchronous code may look like this:

```
void A()
{
  Debug.WriteLine("pre B");
  B();
  Debug.WriteLine("post B");
}

void B()
{
  Debug.WriteLine("inside B");
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  Debug.WriteLine("still inside B");
}
```

The corresponding asynchronous code would be:

```
async Task A()
{
  Debug.WriteLine("pre B");
  await B();
  Debug.WriteLine("post B");
}

async Task B()
{
  Debug.WriteLine("inside B");
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  Debug.WriteLine("still inside B");
}
```

Even though the code will now execute asynchronously, the output is exactly the same as the synchronous version.

If you want one method to start *concurrent* operations and *then* continue, you can just call the methods and then do the `await` later:

```
async Task A()
{
  // Start both tasks
  Debug.WriteLine("pre B1");
  Task b1 = B();
  Debug.WriteLine("post B1, pre B2");
  Task b2 = B();
  Debug.WriteLine("post B2, pre await");

  // (asynchronously) wait for them to complete
  await Task.WhenAll(b1, b2);
  Debug.WriteLine("post await");
}

async Task B()
{
  Debug.WriteLine("inside B");
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  Debug.WriteLine("still inside B");
}
```

And in this case, you'll see both executions of `B` start, and `A` will continue executing after both `B`s complete.

Comment: I'm answering as what im getting after testing is different than what you proposed. Have to Write code so posting it as answer

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code now it looks like

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pre A");
            A();
            Console.WriteLine("Post A");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static async Task A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("pre B");
            await B();
            Console.WriteLine("post B");
        }

        static async Task B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside B");
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("still inside B");
        }

    }
}
```

And output i'm getting is as suspected.
Pre A

pre B

inside B

Post A

still inside B

post B

So you see as soon as I'm hitting **await Task.Delay(10000);** the control goes back to Main method, as evident from the fact that its printing **Post A** before **still inside B** also after **Console.WriteLine("Post A");** It waits for **Console.ReadKey();** only because as soon as I hit any key execution stops. It doesn't wait for **Console.WriteLine("still inside B");**.

> So simple yet so strange. .net!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that it runs sync cuz you`re using await statements, which waits for your methods to be done.
So if you want to get result like 2d variant - try not to use await

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. Async/Await means that the method is suspended until the task is complete. That task runs asynchronously but the current thread waits for it and the current thread is no blocked.

This is specially useful if you don't want to block the ui thread when a method waits for a result that may be long to come.

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx)

> **Async Improves Responsiveness**
>
> Asynchrony is essential for activities that are potentially blocking,
>   such as when your application accesses the web. Access to a web
>   resource sometimes is slow or delayed. If such an activity is blocked
>   within a synchronous process, the entire application must wait. **In an
>   asynchronous process, the application can continue with other work**
>   that doesn't depend on the web resource until the potentially blocking
>   task finishes.
>
> The following table shows typical areas where asynchronous programming
>   improves responsiveness. The listed APIs from the .NET Framework 4.5
>   and the Windows Runtime contain methods that support async
>   programming.
>
> Application area
>
> Supporting APIs that contain async methods
>
> Web access
>
> HttpClient , SyndicationClient
>
> Working with files
>
> StorageFile, StreamWriter, StreamReader, XmlReader
>
> Working with images
>
> MediaCapture, BitmapEncoder, BitmapDecoder
>
> WCF programming
>
> Synchronous and Asynchronous Operations
>
> Asynchrony proves **especially valuable for applications that access the
>   UI thread** because all UI-related activity usually shares one thread.
>   If any process is blocked in a synchronous application, all are
>   blocked. Your application stops responding, and you might conclude
>   that it has failed when instead it's just waiting

For example, you can have a method that returns a value.

```
public async Task<int> LongComputation()
```

And then, in your code you have:

```
var result = await LongComputation();
```

The current thread is not blocked. When the result is available, you get it in your variable and you can continue with it in your current thread.

---

If you want to launch a new task asynchronously, you can do it like that

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("async start");
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    Debug.WriteLine("async end");
                });
```

---

In your method B, you can try the following

```
async void B()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("pre C");
    var taskC = C();
    Debug.WriteLine("post C")
    await taskC;
}
```

Comment: So how can i check that current thread is not blocked, from my example its seems that its running one after another and function A() is waiting for function D() to complete.

Comment: Also Task.Factory.StartNew or Task.Run(()=>)  will create a new Thread that a complete different story. Isn't it?

Comment: A() will always wait for D() if you use await. For example, if D() returns a value, you can use it afterwards in A(). If A() did not wait faor D(), it would not be able to use this value.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` helps you creating a new task that runs asynchronously. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: I guess I'm confusing stuff, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#Anchor_2 says something different?

Comment: Also in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#Anchor_1 its clearly mentioned that  "  // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync.
    //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete.
    //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync.
    //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete. 
    //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask." . So sequence of my output should be different.

Comment: In your first link, you can see that the task `getStringTask` is launched but is `awaited` later. The `getStringTask` is launched in another thread. The current thread continues and `await` it later.

Comment: It is not Waiting the control goes back to the called method. When when the task is complete its result is going to that method. who is awaiting the it. As given by second link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95663/discussion-between-dinkar-thakur-and-daniel).